# IIS Url-Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use IIS7 Url Rewrite module rewrite 
**services.mydomain.com/some-file-here** to **mydomain.webhost.com/folder/some-file-here**

The rule is as follows:

```
Pattern = ^services.mydomain.com/(.*)$
Action = Rewrite
Rewrite URL = http://mydomain.webhost.com/folder/{R:1}
```

The problem is IIS keeps giving me 404 not found errors. I've been stuck at this for days now. Any ideas?

Comment: does the URL redirect successfully? 404 on which page?

Comment: When I visit say services.mydomain.com/Hello, I get the 404. The url doesn't seem to redirect at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have your pattern wrong. It should not include domain name or query string there -- only path without leading slash. See the working rule below:

```xml
<rule name="MyRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(some-file-here)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^services\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain.webhost.com/folder/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The above rule will only trigger if host name is `services.mydomain.com`. If you do not require such additional condition (which is optional) then just remove these 3 lines: `<conditions>...</conditions>`

Also, the above rule will only do one specific redirect from `services.mydomain.com/some-file-here` to `mydomain.webhost.com/folder/some-file-here`. If you need to redirect ANY file like that, then use this one instead:

```xml
<rule name="MyRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^services\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain.webhost.com/folder/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```