# URL Rewrite to different sub domain on different server - IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have the following setup:

Specific DNS per server 4 servers in total:

1. app1.domain.com
2. app2.domain.com
3. app3.domain.com
4. app4.domain.com

Shared DNS that is hosted on all servers
www.domain.com

What I want is to rewrite specific URLS to a specific server. For example, 
www.domain.com/account may rewrite to app1.domain.com/account Is this possible if so how?
Keep in mind that a given account can only live on one server at a time.

Comment: You can't rewrite to a different domain (or subdomain). You can *redirect* to a different server (either with 301 or 302 status code).

Comment: You can redirect to another domain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313462/iis-url-rewrite.  Notice, mydomain.com -> webhost.com.   The issue will be detecting which "account" lives on which subdomain.  To help on that detection, I'd need more information.

On a side, are you trying distribute load across these subdomains?  If so, it would be better to have each domain share a common database and use a standard loadbalancer to distribute the load.